# React image not rendering from the database

Tags: javascript, reactjs

can you all please help point out what could be wrong with my code. im try to render data from mongoose db, other data rendered well but the image isnt rendering. thanks you all

App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import DbData from './screen/DbData';
import FileUploadScreen from './screen/FileUploadScreen';
import {getallSingleFiles} from './data'

function App() {
  const [fetchdata, setFetchdata] = useState([])
 
  
    
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/get').then(res => {
      if(res.ok){
        return res.json()
      }
    }).then(jsonRes => setFetchdata(jsonRes))
  })
      
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <h3 className="text-danger font-weight-bolder text-center">File Upload</h3>
      </div>
      <FileUploadScreen />
      <h1>data list</h1>
      {fetchdata.map(item =>{
        return (
          <div key={item._id}>
            <h4>{item.title}</h4>
            <img src={item.filePath} alt={item.fileName} />
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

router.js

```
router.get('/get', (req, res) =>{
    SingleFile.find().then(fetchdata => res.json(fetchdata))
})
```

add route

```
const singleFileUpload = async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const file = new SingleFile( {
            fileName: req.file.originalname,
            filePath: req.file.path,
            fileType: req.file.mimetype,
            fileSize: fileSizeFormatter(req.file.size, 2), //2dp 
            title: req.body.title
        })
        await file.save()
        res.status(201).send('File Uploaded Successfully!');
    }catch(error) {
        // res.status(400).send(error.message + 'Data not save')
        res.status(400).json({msg: 'No file upload.please, fill the required filed'})
    }
}

const fileSizeFormatter = (bytes, decimal) => {
    if(bytes === 0){
        return '0 Bytes';
    }
    const dm  = decimal || 2;
    const sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB']
    const index = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1000))
    return parseFloat((bytes /Math.pow(1000, index)).toFixed(dm)) + '' + sizes[index]
}

router.post('/singleFile', upload, singleFileUpload )
```

error from the console

```
GET http://localhost:3000/uploads/2021-08-18T16-40-37.949Z-back4-min%20(1).jpg 404 (Not Found)

GET http://localhost:3000/uploads/2021-08-19T08-36-59.674Z-cap1.png 404 (Not Found)
```

note. the title is rendering but the image isnt rendering
note. the title is rendering but the image isnt rendering
note. the title is rendering but the image isnt rendering

Comment: Images don't exist. So they can't be rendered!!! You receive `404` error

Comment: thanks Danial, there are images in the database and inside the uploads folder too.

Comment: Load this in your browser `http://localhost:3000/uploads/2021-08-19T08-36-59.674Z-cap1.png`. Does it load?

Comment: it redirected me to the localhost:3000 page and rendered the page

Comment: It means you can't access that file

Comment: okay, please is there anything wrong with the code ?

Comment: Do you have a REST API running on http://localhost:3000/? If yes, could you please let me know if it's nodejs or something else so I can tell you where the images should be?. Hint: on a public folder.

Comment: thank you all, the image now rendering fine. i restructure the code. then on multer disc storage, i specify the specify path like this "  './client/public/uploads' ", initially it was just "./uploads/"